# Date conversion to specified format not working for all values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a code that converts all the dates in the specified date column to the specified date format. In case the date is invalid or empty, it gets replaced by the replacement value specified.

My code works as expected for all values except the following two:

1. 12-2012-18 (Gets considered invalid & is being replaced by the replacement value).
2. 2008,12,02 (Converted to "02,01,2008" instead of "02,12,2008" or "12,02,2008")

**CODE:**

## # # Date Formatting

```
def date_fun(df, col_name, date_format, replace_value):
                
            # Convert column values to string
            df[col_name] = df[col_name].astype(str)
            
            # Convert serial date values to datetime values
            def handle_serial_date(val):
                try:
                    return pd.to_datetime(float(val), unit='D')
                except:
                    return val
            df[col_name] = df[col_name].apply(handle_serial_date)
            
            # Convert regular date values to datetime values
            df[col_name] = pd.to_datetime(df[col_name], errors='coerce')
            
            # Replace invalid or null dates with the specified value (if any)
            if replace_value is not None:
                replace_value = pd.to_datetime(str(replace_value), errors='coerce') # convert replace_value to datetime format
                df[col_name] = df[col_name].fillna(replace_value) # replace invalid or null dates with replace_value
                               
            # Convert the datetime values to the specified format
            df[col_name] = df[col_name].dt.strftime(date_format)
            
            new_data = df[col_name].to_dict()
                        
            return new_data
```

**Input & Output:**

```
Input:
"0": 25.09.2019
"1": 9/16/2015
"2": 10.12.2017
"3": 02.12.2014
"4": 08-Mar-18
"5": 08-12-2016
"6": 26.04.2016
"7": 05-03-2016
"8": 24.12.2016
"9": 10-Aug-19
"10": abc
"11": 05-06-2015
"12": 12-2012-18
"13": 24-02-2010
"14": 2008,13,02
"15": 16-09-2015
"16": 23-01-1992, 7:45
"17": 
"18": 2nd December 2018
"19": 45678
"20": 798

Output: (format= m-d-Y, replacement value=05-06-1987 (for null & invalid dates))

            "0": "09-25-2019",
            "1": "09-16-2015",
            "2": "10-12-2017",
            "3": "02-12-2014",
            "4": "03-08-2018",
            "5": "08-12-2016",
            "6": "04-26-2016",
            "7": "05-03-2016",
            "8": "12-24-2016",
            "9": "08-10-2019",
            "10": "05-06-1987",
            "11": "05-06-2015",
            "12": "05-06-1987",
            "13": "02-24-2010",
            "14": "02-01-2008",
            "15": "09-16-2015",
            "16": "01-23-1992",
            "18": "12-02-2018",
            "19": "01-23-2095",
            "20": "03-09-1972"
```

The problematic rows are:  12 & 14. Why is my code not working on these two values?

Answer (score 1):

The line you convert your date column into datetime with errors set to coerce, entries like `2008,12,02` that couldn't be converted into a valid datetime are set to null. Thus, your line that handles special data format isn't actually being used at all. Entries like `2008,12,02` after being set to NaN are handled by your replace NaN step.

If you want to keep data points that failed datetime conversion, you can set errors to `ignore` and handle them separately.

Comment: ',' as a separator is not supported by Pandas. I replaced comma with other separators & it worked. But what about '12-2018-18'? That's in a valid date format which works for other values, but not the above combination.

Comment: Ohh, yeah, comma isn't supported. For 12-2018-18, that looks like a %m-%Y-%d  format. Again, I am not sure how you implement your 'date_format' parameter on this function, but if it has the value to handle this format, it should work fine